# Как правильо указать muliport для для source и destination port?

Tags: linux, сеть, iptables

Мне нужно, чтобы все пакеты с портами 4222,6379 не попадали под правила и правило нужно одной строкой так как пакет улетит иначе в очередь. Я пытался сделать так.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p tcp -m tcp ! --sport 4222 ! --dport 4222 -J NFQUEUE --queue-num 100
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p tcp -m tcp ! --sport 6379 ! --dport 6379 -J NFQUEUE --queue-num 100
```

Но логично пакеты с портом 6379  попадают под верхнее правило.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport ! --sport 4222,6379  ! --dport 4222,6379  -J NFQUEUE --queue-num 100
```

а данное правило не срабатывает, как быть ?

Comment: Глянь тут к примеру. https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/5779251

Answer (score 2):

> данное правило не срабатывает, как быть ?

Общий принцип: отфильтровывай пакеты предыдущими правилами.

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --sport 4222 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --sport 6379 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 4222 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 100
```

Если не хочешь сразу принимать пакеты, а, возможно, обрабатывать их другими правилами, то создай отдельную цепочку:

```
iptables -t raw -N maybe_nfqueue
iptables -t raw -A maybe_nfqueue -p tcp --sport 4222 -j RETURN
iptables -t raw -A maybe_nfqueue -p tcp --dport 4222 -j RETURN
# ...
iptables -t raw -A maybe_nfqueue -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 100

iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j maybe_nfqueue
```

Ну и раз `-m multiport` упомянут, то в данном случае можно обойтись и одним правилом (внимание на то что они *--port**s***):

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m multiport ! --ports 4222,6379 \
         -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 100
```